# Kemet: Controlling another Player's pyramid and Victory point

Tags: kemet

It is clear that when you capture another player's pyramid you gain the ability to use that pyramid and also the temporary victory point.

If you willfully abandon the pyramid by moving the occupying troop, does the player who's city the pyramid resides in automatically gain control of the pyramid.  Do they automatically get the temporary victory point back?

A more summary question might be:  Does a player who has a pyramid with no units on it in his home city automatically control the pyramid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a player who has a pyramid with no units on it in his home city automatically controls the pyramid.

Here's some supporting threads from BGG.  Look at the second (italicized) line.

From BGG "[Kemet Supplementary Rules](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1110151/kemet-supplementary-rules-chas)"
(emphasis mine)

> **Pyramids:** A zero level pyramid means no pyramid is present. *You control any pyramid in your city that is unoccupied.* You control any
>   pyramid in an enemy city where you are in sole occupation, and may
>   upgrade it (getting its temporary VP) and/or use it to buy tiles of
>   that color and teleport from it.

This is also backed up by the "[City Control Question](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/969485/city-control-question)" thread.